# Conclusion from many-to-many relationship

Tags: modeling

Raw data as below:
on the left, there are teams of musicians.
On the right, there are the features of the music the team composed, for style, duration and musical instrument.

```
[Lucas, Liam, James] : [Indie rock, Long, Tuba]
[Mason, Isabella, James] : [Electronic, Long, Piano]
[Benjamin, William, Olivia] : [Experimental, Medium, Ukulele]
[James, Charlotte, Isabella] : [Dance, Medium, Tuba]
...
[Oliver, Olivia, Sophia] : [Ambient, Medium, Piano]
[Noah, Mason, Isabella] : [Hip-hop, Medium, Tuba]
[Isabella, Harper, Liam] : [Ambient, Short, Ukulele]
[James, Emma, Charlotte] : [Dance, Medium, Double bass]
[Mason, Mia, Ethan] : [Experimental, Clip, Flute]
[James, Sophia, Harper] : [Ambient, Short, Ukulele]
```

For example, “[Lucas, Liam, James] : [Indie rock, Long, Tuba]” means, Lucas, Liam and James ever worked together, composed a long Indie rock style song, used Tuba (a musical instrument)

The historical data quantity is on hundreds. When giving a new team, that a combination never in the existing data. What’s the way to infer the features of the music the new team’s going to compose?

I am thinking, to break the historical data into individuals. That is, taking James as an example, his history (in the teams James ever in) is:

```
[Indie rock, Long, Tuba]
[Electronic, Long, Piano]
[Dance, Medium, Tuba]
[Dance, Medium, Double bass]
[Ambient, Short, Ukulele]
```

It tells when James is in the new team, there’s a higher chance that the song is Dance style, Medium in length and using Tuba.

When putting all such data of all team members in the new team, it suggests the features of the new music.

Does it make sense? What would be a better way?

Comment: Suppose that John is in six teams, two of which also contain George. George is in those two teams plus three more (total of five). Four of John's teams used piano and the two with George used guitar. George's other three teams used tuba. So, independently, you might give John a 1/3 chance of using guitar and George a 2/5 chance of using guitar, but when together John and George have always used guitar (two times out of two). Does that carry any extra weight?

Comment: @prubin, Professor, thanks for the interesting comment! brilliant point at the 'together'! But no extra weight is carried.

Comment: Without knowing something about how the composition process works (is choice of instrument a majority vote, is the first team member responsible for picking instrument and the second responsible for style, ...), I'm not sure you can do better than an almost blind guess.

Comment: By the way, does a given trio of people occur at most once in the data, or could Isabella, Harper and Liam collaborate multiple times on different pieces (with differences in instrument, style and/or duration)?

Comment: @prubin, Professor, thanks for the comments again. Yes, it's mostly a blind guess. The combination seems random and who's the main contributors in the team is unknown too.

Comment: and, the cases suggest that, even the same trio of people appear in the same team again, the music product might be totally different from what they ever had.

Comment: So I take it that it is possible for multiple records in the data set to involve the same three people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hesitate to suggest this, for fear it will get one of my degrees revoked, but here goes. I'm going to use the term "target" generically for the thing you are try to guess. It might be one feature of the music (e.g., the instrument), but it also might be the triplet of style, duration and instrument. The reason for guessing triplets as a whole would be that guessing the features individually might lead you to a combination that is unlikely if not impossible (because long folk songs played on a tuba just don't exist).

Let's say that Larry, Gary and Mary are a new trio. We will make three thoroughly unsupported assumptions: that individuals pick feature values randomly; that choices are made independent of who their teammates are, what their teammates pick, and anything else you can think of; and that majority rules within the team. So for the new trio to select target value $j$, it must be a majority choice. If $p_{ij}$ is the true probability of musician $i$ picking target value $j$, the probability of $j$ being the majority choice is $$p_{Lj}\cdot p_{Gj}\cdot p_{Mj} + p_{Lj}\cdot p_{Gj}\cdot (1-p_{Mj}) + p_{Lj}\cdot (1- p_{Gj})\cdot p_{Mj} + (1-p_{Lj})\cdot p_{Gj}\cdot p_{Mj},$$where the terms are respectively unanimous choice, Mary dissenting, Gary dissenting and Larry dissenting. For each individual $i$ and each possible value $j$ of the target, we estimate $p_{ij}$ with the proportion $\hat{p}_{ij}$ of records involving individual $i$ that match target value $j$.

That gives you a "likelihood" of each possible value $j$ of the target.

Comment: superb! thanks for the suggestion!